# Using Variables to add to Bash Dictionary

Tags: bash, syntax, associative-array

Trying to create a dynamic set of Key-Value pairs through a series of for loops that basically pull from a JSON file to create a series of arrays that are then iterated through to define the key-value pairs.

The issue I am having is that I keep getting the following error when I run the script:

`array[key]=value: command not found`

The information it should be writing to the array looks correct, just gives me that error.

Here's how I am trying to add to the arrays.

`$array[$key]=$value`

Not quite sure if I am trying to do something that simply cannot be done.

I've tried a few variations of the script, all with the same "command not found" error.

Here is the full script as written at the moment:

```
#!/bin/bash 

backupTargets=()
#currently active nodes
nodeArray=()
#add proxmox api token
pveTOK=FOO

get_nodes () { 
#grab currently active nodes 
curl -s -k -H "Authorization: PVEAPIToken=$pveTOK" https:///api2/json/nodes | jq . > nodes
#use jq to extract inital data from the curl command, remove returns with tr and use sed to clean things up to make it ready to be placed 
#in an array
nodes=$(jq [.data[].node] nodes | tr -d '\n'| sed 's/\[//g; s/\]//g; s/ //g; s/,/ /g; s/\"//g')
nodeArray=($nodes)
}

declare_variables () {
for node in "${nodeArray[@]}"
do
declare -A $node
done
}

get_backupVMs () {
#some nested for loops that iterate over the nodes to create a dictionary that contains each vm and the associated tags
for node in "${nodeArray[@]}"
do
hosts=()
curl -s -k -H "Authorization: PVEAPIToken=$pveTOK" https:///api2/json/nodes/$node/qemu | jq . > $node
name=$(jq [.data[].name] $node | tr -d '\n'| sed 's/\[//g; s/\]//g; s/ //g; s/,/ /g; s/\"//g')
hosts+=($name)
for host in "${hosts[@]}"
do
tags=$(jq '.data[] | select(.name=='\"$host\"').tags' $node | sed 's/\[//g; s/\]//g; s/ //g; s/;/ /g; s/\"//g')
$node[$host]=$tags
done
done
}

get_nodes
declare_variables
get_backupVMs
```

Comment: Remove the $ in front of `array`. `$` is a special character for the shell indicating **parameter expansion**. When you start a line with $, the first word is never interpreted as a variable assignement, but as a command. That's why you get the error _command not found_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant part of your code is basically:

```
for node in "${nodeArray[@]}"; do
    declare -A $node
done

for node in "${nodeArray[@]}"; do
    $node[$host]=$tags
done
```

Bash does not support variable name indirection written like this.

Assignments are only recognized if the LHS is a valid variable name, optionally followed by something in brackets, followed by an equal sign, followed by the value to be assigned. However `$node` before expansion is not a valid variable name. (See: [assignment()](https://github.com/gitGNU/gnu_bash/blob/bc007799f0e1362100375bb95d952d28de4c62fb/general.c#L393) in the Bash source-code.)

Because Bash does not recognise your assignment as being one, it tries to execute the word as a command, which gives the errors you have seen.

---

There is almost certainly a better way to structure the logic of your code so that this type of indirection is not needed but a quick-and-dirty fix is to use a [nameref](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html) in the second loop (the first loop remains unchanged):

```
for node in "${nodeArray[@]}"; do
    declare -n ref=$node
    ref[$host]=$tags
done
```

Comment: This seems to have at least gotten rid of the errors, however it doesn't seem to create the output I need, seemingly changing every time the script is run when I do a quick `echo  ${foo[@]}` where foo is a known node name created by the `declare -n ref-$node` Looks like I will have to find a better structure for the logic after all. If there are any suggestions on where to start looking or reading about a better way to do this, I always appreciated a good push in the right direction.

Comment: @DavisSayer I assume `ref-$node` is a typo? Note that you have to perform a `declare -n` every time you change the destination of the reference - it has to be **inside** the loop

Comment: Ach, yeah, that was supposed to read `ref=$node` and it is being declared at the beginning of the loop `for node in "${nodeArray[@]}"` - basically I removed the `declare_variables` function from the script and integrated the nameref into the beginning of the `get_backupVMs` function.

Comment: @DavisSayer I expected you to retain the first for loop unchanged (I elided it to focus on the change). You still need to `declare -A` your actual associative arrays, otherwise the `ref[$host]` assignment will be treated as applying to an indexed array and `$host` will be cast to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to declare the associative array:

```
declare -A array
```

In the assignment, don't use the dollar sign on the left hand side:

```
array[$key]=$value
```

Also, make sure you're running the script in bash, not some other shell. Associative arrays aren't supported everywhere (e.g. in `dash`).

Comment: I suggest to use double quotes: `array[$key]="$value"`

Comment: @Cyrus: They aren't needed in assignments.

Comment: @choroba The arrays are declared earlier in the script based on the contents of another loop. The name of the array itself is a variable in the for loop, thus the $ in $array. Is there a better way of looping and adding to an array as a variable?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a pseudo multidimensional array (*as bash supports only 1 dimension you have to create special keys*)

```
declare -A array
for n in ${nodeArray[@]}; do
   for h in ${hosts[@]}; do
     array["$n,$h"]="tags $n $h"
   done
done
```